# Replace a column values with its mean of groups in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame as

```
Page    Line    y
1        2      3.2
1        2      6.1
1        3      7.1
2        4      8.5
2        4      9.1
```

I have to replace column y with values of its mean in groups. I can do that grouping using one column using this code.

```
df['y'] = df['y'].groupby(df['Page'], group_keys=False).transform('mean')
```

**I am trying to replace the values of y by mean of groups by 'Page' and 'Line'. Something like this,**

```
Page    Line    y
1        2      4.65
1        2      4.65
1        3      7.1
2        4      8.8
2        4      8.8
```

I have searched through a lot of answers on this site but couldn't find this application. Using python3 with pandas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need list of columns names, [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) parameter `by`:

> **by** : mapping, function, label, or **list of labels**
>
> Used to determine the groups for the groupby. If by is a function, it’s called on each value of the object’s index. If a dict or Series is passed, the Series or dict VALUES will be used to determine the groups (the Series’ values are first aligned; see .align() method). If an ndarray is passed, the values are used as-is determine the groups. A label or list of labels may be passed to group by the columns in self. Notice that a tuple is interpreted a (single) key.

```
df['y'] = df.groupby(['Page', 'Line'])['y'].transform('mean') 
print (df)
   Page  Line     y
0     1     2  4.65
1     1     2  4.65
2     1     3  7.10
3     2     4  8.80
4     2     4  8.80
```

Your solution should be changed to this syntactic sugar - pass Series in list:

```
df['y'] = df['y'].groupby([df['Page'], df['Line']]).transform('mean')
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want this:

```
df['y'] = df.groupby(['Page', 'Line']).transform('mean')
```

Comment: OK, sorry. In last days this sometimes failed.

Answer (score 2):

[**@jezrael's approach**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51043418/2336654) is idiomatic.  Use that approach!

### `np.bincount` and `pd.factorize`

This should be pretty fast.  However, this is a specialized solution to a specific problem and doesn't do well if you want to generalize.  Also, if you need to deal with `np.nan`, you'd have to incorporate more logic.

```
f, u = pd.factorize(list(zip(df.Page, df.Line)))
df.assign(y=(np.bincount(f, df.y) / np.bincount(f))[f])

   Page  Line     y
0     1     2  4.65
1     1     2  4.65
2     1     3  7.10
3     2     4  8.80
4     2     4  8.80
```

What this is doing is:

- `pd.factorize` identifies the groups
- `np.bincount(f)` is counting how many items in each group
- `np.bincount(f, df.y)` is summing the values of column `y` within each group
- `(np.bincount(f, df.y) / np.bincount(f))` finds the mean
- `(np.bincount(f, df.y) / np.bincount(f))[f]` slices to present the same length as the original array

---

### `set_index` and `map`

This is me being silly.  Don't use this.

```
cols = ['Page', 'Line']
df.assign(y=df.set_index(cols).index.map(df.groupby(cols).y.mean()))

   Page  Line     y
0     1     2  4.65
1     1     2  4.65
2     1     3  7.10
3     2     4  8.80
4     2     4  8.80
```

- Use `groupby` (without `transform`) to get a mapping of `tuple` -> `mean`
- Use `set_index` as a convenient way to make pandas produce the tuples
- `Index` objects have a `map` method, so we'll use that